# Trigonometry in triangle, can't understand an example from my textbook

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

I'm stuck with this from a few hours. There is an exercise in my textbook, which is solved and it's must be used as an example, however  I can't understand it. Here's the exercises + how it's solved.
Given that:
$$
\alpha + \beta + \gamma = \pi 
$$
proof that
$$
\sin(\alpha) + \sin(\beta) + \sin(\gamma) = 4 * \cos\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{\beta}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{\gamma}{2}\right)
$$

Solution from my textbook:
$$
\sin(\alpha) + \sin(\beta) + \sin(\gamma) = 2*\sin\left(\frac{\alpha+ \beta}{2}\right)*\cos\left(\frac{\alpha-\beta}{2}\right) + \sin(\pi - (\alpha + \beta))
$$
$$
= 2*\sin\left(\frac{\alpha+ \beta}{2}\right)*\cos\left(\frac{\alpha-\beta}{2}\right) + 2*\sin\left(\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}\right)*\cos\left(\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}\right) 
$$
$$
= 2*\sin\left(\frac{\alpha+ \beta}{2}\right)*\left(\cos\left(\frac{\alpha-\beta}{2}\right) + \cos\left(\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}\right)\right)
$$
$$
= 4 * \sin\left(\frac{\pi -\gamma}{2}\right) * \cos\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right) * cos\left({\frac{\beta}{2}}\right) 
$$
$$
= 4 * \cos \left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right) * \cos\left(\frac{\beta}{2}\right) * \cos\left(\frac{\gamma}{2}\right)
$$

The thing I can't understand is how from 
$$
\sin(\pi - (\alpha + \beta))
$$

Become

$$
2*\sin\left(\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}\right)*\cos\left(\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}\right) 
$$

I think this is the formula for 
$$
\sin(2*\alpha)
$$

Comment: $\sin(\pi - (\alpha + \beta)) =2\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2})  \cos(\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}) =2\cos(\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2})  \sin(\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2})$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using$$\sin(A-B)=\sin A\cos B-\cos A\sin B$$$$\sin(2C)=2\sin C\cos C$$gives you$$\begin{align}\sin\left(\pi-(\alpha+\beta)\right)&=\sin\pi\cos(\alpha+\beta)-\cos\pi\sin(\alpha+\beta)\\&=0\cdot \cos(\alpha+\beta)-(-1)\cdot\sin(\alpha+\beta)\\&=\sin(\alpha+\beta)\\&=\sin\left(2\cdot\left(\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}\right)\right)\\&=2\sin\left(\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}\right)\end{align}$$

Comment: Yep, thank all of you.

Answer (score 0):

One more observation and you're there.

Note that $\sin(\pi - (\alpha+\beta)) = \sin(\alpha + \beta)$.

Then application of the double-angle formula is clear.

Comment: I know that $$ \sin(\pi - (\alpha + \beta) = \sin(\alpha + \beta)$$
However it's never said taht $$ \alpha = \beta$$

Comment: Why do you need $\alpha=\beta$?  The part you said you were not understanding doesn't depend on $\alpha$ equaling $\beta$.

Comment: I don't understand how the formula for double-angle is applied here since it's about $$ 2 *\alpha$$